# Random error in Unix shell script

Tags: sql, bash, unix, plsql

I have a shell script which in turn calls sql file. Its a bash shell running in UNIX. Following is the main steps taken in script.
1) Generate Term file
2) Remove previous day's Term and Rpt file from utility directory.
3) Copy Term file from Run directory to Utility directory.
4) Run the sql file
5) Copy the output, RPT file from Utility to Run directory.

Here is the code snippet:

```
> RUN_DIR/nj.terms
if [[ -s RUN_DIR/nj.terms ]] then
rm -f /utl/nj.terms
rm -f /utl/nj.rpt
cp RUN_DIR/nj.terms utl

/bin/sqlplus USER PSWD @sql

cp utl/nj.RPT RUN_DIR

fi
```

I get following error from sql output as :
ORA-29283 - Invalid file operation.

Mostly this error is due to absence of Term file whenever the sql runs. Due this error RPT file will not be generated and cause failure in following copy command (cp utl/nj.RPT RUN_DIR).After the failure, when we checked the Term file ,it was present in Utl directory.

This error occurs randomly. Is there any chance system takes more time to copy the Term file to Utility directory and before completing it sql was run? It would be great if someone can help me in this situation.

Comment: This script runs fine without any syntax error. Above line just indicate if the Term file is present in Run directory, only then rm, cp command should be called along with sql.

Comment: if `[[-s RUN_DIR/nj.terms]] then` is a syntax error. Try if `[[ -s RUN_DIR/nj.terms ]]; then` (note the semicolon and added spaces)

Comment: I have not copied my exact script here as it violates the rule. It is just the code sample.As i mentioned earlier, this script does not throw any syntax error.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean about _the rule_ but it's distracting to have a script with syntax errors in your question, especially if that's not the code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: So you copied the script without any syntax errors, then introduced some syntax errors & asking community to ignore the syntax errors, but look for any other possible errors? :D

Comment: @TomFenech: You are right about the spaces.Thanks. I have corrected it now. However a semicolon is not required after "if" statement. My code is in Remote desktop. I can not copy it here.

Comment: @user1768029 on the contrary, `then` should begin a new statement, so there needs to be either a semicolon after the previous statement or `then` should be moved to a new line.

Comment: @TomFenech: which shell are you trying ? This is a single statement here in bash

Comment: No it's not!: ``$ echo "$SHELL" => /bin/bash
$ if [[ a = a ]] then => -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `then'``